# I want to read and process / validate against API response JDBC JSON response in JMETER

Tags: jmeter

JDBC request:
[image]

JDBC Response:
[image]

Is it possible to extract each value from json and validate ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Given your configuration the response from the database is stored into `jsonresult_1` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html).

So you can add several [JSON Extractors](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor) and point them to the `jsonresult_1` JMeter Variable to extract the values from the JSON response via [JsonPath queries](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started).

Example:

[image]